# Confused with Viewer API vs example, passing options to extensions

Tags: javascript, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

I am confused as the examples on how to use the Viewer don't seem to match the documentation of the API, some functions are not in the docs or their signature is different.

Base on the examples code, how do I pass options to the extensions I instantiate? I would like to pass my extension a callback.

Thanks!

Comment: are you using http://developer.autodesk.com samples & documentation?

Comment: Yes, I am using it :)

Comment: which sample are you having problems? (if anything is inconsistent, I can review it).

Comment: For example the example use Autodesk.A360ViewingApplication but there isn't this object in the API doc, same for method viewerApp.loadDocumentWithItemAndObject.

Comment: thanks @e-Jah, I'll check the tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to fix the doc so it does not rely anymore on the undocumented A360 viewer additional code, which is supposed to be internal. Sorry for the incovenience, we will do this asap...

For the time being, you can use the code from my [viewer boilerplate sample](https://github.com/leefsmp/view.and.data-boilerplate):

```
function initializeViewer(containerId, urn) {

    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(urn, function (model) {

      var rootItem = model.getRootItem();

      // Grab all 3D items
      var geometryItems3d = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(
        rootItem,
        { 'type': 'geometry', 'role': '3d' },
        true);

      // Grab all 2D items
      var geometryItems2d = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(
        rootItem,
        { 'type': 'geometry', 'role': '2d' },
        true);

      var domContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);

      //UI-less Version: viewer without any Autodesk buttons and commands
      //viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(domContainer);

      //GUI Version: viewer with controls
      viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(domContainer);

      viewer.initialize();

      viewer.setLightPreset(8);

      //Button events - two buttons to load/unload a sample extension
      // Irrelevant to viewer code itself
      var loadBtn = document.getElementById('loadBtn');

      loadBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){

        loadExtension(viewer);
      });

      var unloadBtn = document.getElementById('unloadBtn');

      unloadBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){

        unloadExtension(viewer);
      });

      // Illustrates how to listen to events
      // Geometry loaded is fired once the model is fully loaded
      // It is safe to perform operation involving model structure at this point
      viewer.addEventListener(
        Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
        onGeometryLoaded);

      //optional
      var options = {
        globalOffset: {
          x: 0, y: 0, z: 0
        }
      }

      // Pick the first 3D item ortherwise first 2D item
      var viewablePath = (geometryItems3d.length ?
        geometryItems3d[0] :
        geometryItems2d[0]);

      viewer.loadModel(
        model.getViewablePath(viewablePath),
        options);

    }, function(err) {

      logError(err);
    });
  }
```

Once the viewer is initialized, you can load independently each extension and pass a callback as follow:

```
var options = {
     onCustomEventFiredByMyExtension: function() {
         console.log('LMV rulez!')
     }
 }

 viewer.loadExtension('MyExtensionId', options)
```

But I think a more elegant approach would be to fire events from the extension itself, which may look like this:

```
 viewer.loadExtension('MyExtensionId')

 var myExtension = viewer.getExtension('MyExtensionId')

 myExtension.on('CustomEvent', function () {
     console.log('LMV still rulez!')
 })
```

See [micro-events](https://github.com/alexanderGugel/micro-events) for a super simple event library.